# Using Reflection to get a class description

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I'm trying to get the Full Class description into a string value. I have designated the classes to Enumerate through, to get back the full description. However; calling ToString() on any class object only provides a summary.

I want the full definition, as in what is shown in the class file (.cs) related to it.

```
public class Expose : System.Attribute
{
    public bool DoExpose;

    public Expose(bool doExpose)
    {
        DoExpose = doExpose;
    }

    public static void DoStuff()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Expose));
        var types = GetTypesWithExposeAttribute(assembly);
        // get full class description - like the Car.cs     
        Console.WriteLine(types.First().FullName);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetTypesWithExposeAttribute(Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.IsDefined(typeof(Expose), true))
            {
                yield return type;
            }
        }
    }
}

[Expose(true)]
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do some reading here on [MSDN Accessing Attributes by Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking about ["xml documentation comments"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

The comments are not part of metadata and can't be accessed via reflection.

If you need additional information to be available via reflection - use attributes. (I.e. [C# documentation comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869934/c-sharp-documentation-comments)).